# Appending data from an NSURLConnection to an NSMutableData object fails

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, nsdata

I'm attempting to retrieve a JSON file from an API for parsing. I'm using an NSURLConnection to get the data. It's delegate receives the response and confirms that the MIME type is `application/json`. However, when the delegate calls this method:

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    NSLog(@"Received route data");
    [self.receivedData appendData:data];
    NSLog(@"Data length: %d", data.length);
    NSLog(@"Data length in property: %d", self.receivedData.length);
}
```

It logs the length of `data` as some integer. However, it logs the length of `receivedData` as 0. This is obviously wrong if there is data being appended to it.

`receivedData` is of the type `NSMutableData` and I use `self.receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init]` when the object containing it is initialized. Is there a mistake I have made in appending the data?

Comment: Although you say you've initialised `self.receivedData`, this sounds very much like it is `nil` in your `connection:didReceiveData:` method - have you checked if that's the case?

Comment: @Mac I checked `self.receivedData` and it was indeed `nil`. It appears that I mistakenly set the property to `weak` and it was being released whenever the method that initialized it was finished and the local pointer went out of scope.

Comment: That would indeed do it. Glad you got it sorted out. Incidentally, since you seem new hereabouts (welcome, by the way), you may not know that we encourage people who have solved their own problem to post the answer - it can be really useful for other people who run into the same problem. As much as I'd love to be able to take credit, you found the root cause on your own, so it'd be great if you could post the details in an answer.

Comment: I'll be sure to do it as soon as I can. Have to wait for the 8 hours due to being new. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Mac: the rep is rightfully yours, make an answer and let the OP accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, I had forgotten to set `self.receivedData` to `strong`. As such, it was being released whenever the method that initialized it went out of scope and causing it to return `nil` elsewhere.